# How to create global variable that each host in a play can read and write in ansible?

Tags: ansible

```
---
hosts: all
vars:
  global_variable: 0 
tasks:
  - name: increment variable
    set_var:
       global_variable: "{{ global_variable + 1   }}"
   -debug: global_variable
```

This won't work as you'll get a fresh instance of global_variable for each host. the output of debug will always be the same, instead of incrementing. 
I tried using localhost's hostvars to share a read/write variable , but you can't assign to it with set_fact: ( how else would you assign a value to it?) 
eg

```
- name: update global variable
    delegate_to: localhost
    connection: local
    set_fact:
      hostvars['localhost']['global_variable']: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['global_variable'] + 1 }}"
```

Results in the error:

```
 FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The variable name 'hostvars['localhost']['global_variable']' is not valid. Variables must start with a letter or underscore character, and contain only letters, numbers and underscores."}
```

Ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: I suspect you are trying to use ansible in a way it wasn't intended, since isn't an ACID database. AFAIK the ordering of tasks isn't guaranteed, and 100% not synchronized against concurrent modification. That said, the 2nd half of your question is almost right, you ust need to remove the unnecessary qualifier: `{"set_fact": {"global_variable": "{{ global_variable + 1 }}" } }`; it's already using `hostvars['localhost']`, since that's what the `delegate_to` does

Comment: You were right on both parts. I modified set_fact, record the output to a file, then wrote ansible tasks to read the output, sort it, and write it to the csv file. <br> That does the job as a short term solution. long term I want to move the function to another system, but later when I get some breathing room from my current project.